# Integração de ERP com wordpress por um XML

Tags: wordpress, xml, xmlhttprequest

Boa tarde galera,
Queria saber se alguem sabe de algum tutorial ou algum livro sobre integrar um ERP no wordpress por um XML.
Preciso fazer com que o woocommerce receba os dados do Xml e os inclua e disponibilize no site, alguem sabe como posso fazer?

Comment: Existe uma maneira que já vi funcionando que consiste no seguinte: Um plugin para importar o XML e fazer os includes updates e deletes no banco ou através das próprias funções do Wordpress. É possível criar, deletar e alterar posts através de funções do Wordpress, então acredito que deve funcionar para os produtos do woocommerce, já que são um _custom posts type_. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Encontrei um plugin que é o all import, ele permite importar xml e adicionar a varios lugares no wordpress, inclusive no woocommerce, obrigado a quem tentou ajudar.

Comment: Que bom amigo!!